# What type should I use if I want to assign 500*(1.00013358^3) to a variable

Tags: c++, c

Trying to write a small program to calculate increased by factor numbers using c++.

I'm trying to assign increased by factor to variable to calculate some numbers.
I always get invalid operands of type `double` and `int`.
What type should I use if I want to assign `500 * (1.00013358^3)` to a variable?
Here's some example that I tried without luck:

```
int i=500 * (1.00013358^3);
```

then:

```
float i =500 * (1.00013358^3);
```

but I always get invalid operands of type double and int

Comment: Now you go back and read a good beginners' tutorial on operators. `^` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks even a minimal knowledge of the language being used.

Comment: The use of `^` is wrong like others have said. Also, the choice of type depends on how much precision you need. `1.00013358` has 9 digits of precision which cannot be hold by a float, and `1.00013358^3` will have ~27 digits of precision which by far exceeds the precision of double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to C++, `^` is for bitwise XOR. If you want to do power-thing, use `pow()`. And both `float` and `double` will work OK for your case.

```
float i = 500 * powf(1.00013358, 3);
```

Comment: Suggest `float i = 500f * powf(1.00013358, 3)`

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your expectation is that `^` is some kind of power operator. But it is not, it is a *bitwise exclusive or* (XOR) and can only be applied to integral types.

You may want to have a look at [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow), from the `cmath` header:

```
double i = 500 * std::pow(1.00013358, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

As `^` isn't the power operator I'm assuming you want (it's in fact the bitwise `xor` operator), you might want to try something like this:

```
double x = 1.00013358;
double i = 500*x*x*x; // i == 500 * std::pow(1.00013358, 3)
```

Comment: and this is `math.pow(i, 4)`, not `math.pow(i, 3)` ;)